# Template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a singly linked list that stores multiple types of item. So I came across templates, but when I tried running the following code, the compiler gives me several linking errors (LNK 2019: unresolved external symbol). I haven't really done anything yet and can't figure out what went wrong. Can anyone please point out my mistake??

singlylinkedlist.h

```
template <class Item>
class SinglyLinkedList
{
public:
    SinglyLinkedList();
    ~SinglyLinkedList();

private:
    template <class I>
    struct Node {
        I item;
        Node<I> *next;
    };
    Node<Item> *head; 
};
```

singlylinkedlist.cpp

```
#include "singlylinkedlist.h"

template <class Item>
SinglyLinkedList<Item>::SinglyLinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "singlylinkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SinglyLinkedList<string> list;
}
```

Comment: You don't need an extra template parameter for the `Node` struct, it's enough to just use the `Item` parameter from the outer class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply πάντα ῥεῖ and Mat. I actually found that my problem was because I need to say declare SinglyLinkedList<string> *list as pointer in main(). I'm not really sure why though..

Comment: Thanks for you comment too,  juanchopanza

Comment: @QQO That doesn't really solve your problem!! Try to initialize this pointer, and you'll have the same compilation errors again.

Comment: You're right, πάντα ῥεῖ, it doesn't work. Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: Un-template your `Node` and have `next` be a pointer to an `Item` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of small issues with the code, for example, you haven't implemented the destructor, and you don't really need to templatize Node. Change your implementation as follows,

```
// singlylinkedlist.h
template <class Item>
class SinglyLinkedList
{
public:
    SinglyLinkedList() : head(NULL) {}
    ~SinglyLinkedList() {}

private:
    struct Node {
        Item item;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *head; 
};

// main.cpp
#include "singlylinkedlist.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SinglyLinkedList<string> list;
}
```

Comment: I found that my problem was with pointers in which I need to declare list as pointer in main(). Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @QQO That doesn't really solve your problem!! Try to initialize this pointer, and you'll have the same compilation errors again.

Comment: I am afraid that you've just deferred the problem. Do what πάντα ῥεῖ said and add `list = new SinglyLinkedList<string>();`

Comment: You guys are right, it doesn't work. I was reading the others' comment and testing mockinterface's code. I can only seem to define template inside header files.

Comment: @QQO _'I can only seem to define template inside header files.'_ Yes! The compiler needs to see the complete template class definition, when it's used somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this line for me, πάντα ῥεῖ. It sounds weird to implement the functions in header files and that's why I had a little doubt. Thanks again, πάντα ῥεῖ and mockinterface! I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement the destructor:

```
template <class Item>
SinglyLinkedList<Item>::~SinglyLinkedList()
{
    //cleanup
}
```

Comment: Declaring list as pointer in main() solves my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @QQO No, it doesn't ...